# How to disable automatic iOS device log syncing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Problem: Xcode will not let me debug a device until crash logs are synced.  Crash logs take a long time to sync, and are rarely, if ever, relevant to what I am actually working on.

Scenario: Tester brings me a device to debug a special issue that I cannot test with the simulator.  Since this device has not been plugged into any Xcode for months (if ever), I have to wait for Xcode to pull all the information off of the device before I may debug my issue.

Ideally, there'd be a preference somewhere to toggle until the rare case where I actually want this behavior.  Note: I still want the device to log its crashes- I simply want my Xcode to not care about them.

Does this toggle exist?